# VBA excel + PAste special shapes

Tags: vba, image, paste

I am having a problem to insert a picture (and save within the document) in a worksheet. I am not an expert in VBA, so I really need someone to help me find the error.

Here is the code:

```
copy/paste image0 Sheets("Ficha_AMV").Select Range("c3").Select Selection.Copy ws.Select Range("c3").Select 'ActiveSheet.Paste ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _ DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

So in C3 in sheet "Ficha_AMV" I have a picture, and my goal is to copy it to a new worksheet ("ws"). I need this picture saved within the ws worksheet, (not with a link).

So I tried

`activesheet.paste`
and it copied with the link

then I tried with

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

and it returned the following error

> Run-time error '1004':PasteSpecialo method of Worksheet class failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it already exists as a picture then use the name of the object

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Ficha_AMV")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")             'change as appropriate

    Dim pic As Shape

    Set pic = wsSource.Shapes("Picture 2")       'change as appropriate

    pic.Copy
    ws.Range("C3").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

If it is not already a picture use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Ficha_AMV")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")             'change as appropriate

    wsSource.Range("C3").CopyPicture
    ws.Range("C3").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```